# linear cryptanalysis of hash function

Tags: hash, linear-cryptanalysis

I have studied linear cryptanalysis for block ciphers, but i did not understand how it works on hash functions. Can you give me an explanation of this attack on hash functions?

Comment: Many hash functions—like MD5, SHA-1, SHA-2—are built out of block ciphers with compositions like Davies–Meyer.

Answer (score 2):

The use of linear cryptanalysis for unkeyed hash functions seems to data back to the article (available [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.4.7077)) below

Handschuh H, Knudsen LR, and Robshaw MJ, *Analysis
of SHA-1 in encryption mode*, published in the *Cryptographers' Track-RSA Conference*, Naccache, D. (Ed.), LNCS 2020, Springer-Verlag, Berlin, pp.70-83, 2001

The authors state:

> SHA was never defined to be used for encryption. However, the compression
>   function can be used for encryption. Each of the 80 steps of SHA-1 (divided into
>   four rounds, each of 20 steps) are invertible in the five A, B, C, D, and E variables
>   used for compression. Therefore, if one inserts a secret key in the message and a
>   plaintext as the initial value, one gets an invertible function from the compression function by simply skipping the last forward addition with the input. 
>   This is the encryption mode of SHA considered in this report. The resulting block cipher is named SHACAL and has been submitted to NESSIE by Naccache and the first
>   author.

Comment: If the linked article contains the relevant information, don't forget to quote/explain it here in the answer. As-is, this currently reads like an answer to "what is the history of linear cryptanalysis of hash functions" rather than `Can you give me an explanation of this attack on hash functions`.